# Flawed AP Calc question? Inflection points.

Tags: calculus

The following question was presented to me by a tutoring student in AP Calculus. It's supposedly from a practice test - not sure if it's official. Here's the issue.

Below I've reproduced the complete graph of some continuous function $f(x)$. The question asks us to identify what $x$ are inflection points and to offer an explanation as to why. My student's teacher provided her class with an answer that $x=2$ is an inflection point. I disagree.

$f'(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=2$ and $f''(x)$ does not exist! Furthermore, there is no tangent at $x=2$. I see no transition from concavity to convexity anywhere here. From the definitions of an inflection point provided in Stewart's and Thomas's textbooks, *no inflection points exist*. Can anyone chime in here? Is anyone aware of an alternate definition of inflection point - especially one that is taught in US high schools - that could have been intended here?

[image: graph of f(t)]

Comment: Yup, I don't see any inflection point in the graph, the question looks flawed to me.

Comment: If $x=2$ is an inflection point, why not $-2$ also? I agree that there are none on this graph.

Comment: $f|_{[-2,2]}$ is concave. $f|_{[2,3]}$ is affine-linear and hence convex (and also concave). So, one **could** say that $f$  transitions from being concave to being convex at $x=2$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Hah! This is why I come here. We can fix this question!

Comment: @PhoemueX, if we allow concavity, rather than strict concavity, in the definition of "inflection point", then we should equally say that every point in $[-4,-2]$ and $[2,3)$ is an inflection point.  This is rather silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I teach inflection points in calculus, I require that the second derivative change sign at a point. So if $f''$ changes from negative to positive at $x$, then I would say that $x$ is an inflection point.

Points where $f'' = 0$ but where $f''$ does not change sign are called "undulation points."

This graph has a very large number of undulation points, and no inflection points.